# Multiple commandlets

Tags: powershell

I am a complete noob with regards to programming logic and some help would be greatly appreciated. My question concerns the Get-WmiObject win32_bios and Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem commandlets in the Try Block. The both work as expected if they are in there without the other, but not together. It produces an email report with all computers in domain that looks something like this:

ServerName    BIOS version                                                                            Serial Number
exserver              DELL - 1 Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 2.7.0           3ZTVDC1

I want to add the model number, but that property is not in win32_bios (at least that I know of). So, I was going to grab it from win32_computersystem. Like I said, them both work, just not together. It always just runs whichever commandlet is first and then  goes to the next computer in the list.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function getthebios {
$badcomp = @()
$CompList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -like "*"' | select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($c in $CompList) {

Try {
 Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $c |
 Select-Object @{l='ServerName';e= {$_.__SERVER} },
 @{l='BIOS version';e = {$_.BIOSVersion} },
 @{l='Serial Number';e = {$_.SerialNumber} }


 Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName $c |
 Select-Object @{l='Model Number';e = {$_.Model} }


 }

 Catch {
 $badcomp += $c
 }

 }
 "the following servers could not be reached:"
 $badcomp
 }
 Send-MailMessage -To person@example.com -From "person@example.com" -SmtpServer     
 server.domain.net -Subject "BIOS Version Report" -body (getthebios | Sort-Object 'BIOS version'   
 | convertTo-Html | out-string ) -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: Please take time to minimize your code. Currently there are a lot of unnecessary lines, like `Get-ADComputer` and `Send-MailMessage`. Make this reproducible on our machines, then we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember reading about functions returning all output. However the output you are using the *second* time would not match the object of the previous one. I imagine it is getting discarded due to a mismatch. What you need to do is create a single object with data from both queries. If you have PowerShell 3.0 this should work in place of your `Try` block

```
 $bios = Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $c | Select-Object __SERVER, BIOSVersion, SerialNumber
 $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName $c | Select-Object Model
 [psCustomObject]@{
    "ServerName" = $bios.__SERVER
    "BIOS version" = $bios.BIOSVersion
    "Serial Number" = $bios.SerialNumber
    "Model" = $computerSystem.Model
 }
```

Capture the output of both `WMI` calls into variables. Output the results from both in a single object. The `Select-Object` statements on both lines are not required but since we only need that data it made sense. Now the outputed data will match. The following would work in 2.0 PowerShell if you have that

```
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "ServerName" = $bios.__SERVER
    "BIOS version" = $bios.BIOSVersion
    "Serial Number" = $bios.SerialNumber
    "Model" = $computerSystem.Model
}
```

**Update from comments**

I noticed this as well. What I did to get past that was to cast it as string

```
"BIOS version" = [string]$bios.BIOSVersion
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Matt. This did the trick...almost. I am running PS Version 4.0 and tried both options. Both options returned the correct data in the email, except the BIOSVersion now comes as "System.String[]" instead of "DELL - 1 Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 2.7.0 ". I'm sure I can figure it out from here. I'll update when that happens. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshuaWieberg If you have not come up with a solution yet see my update in answer.

Comment: Awesome. I ended up changing it to the Name property. '"Bios version" = $bios.Name' and that seems to have worked also. Thanks again, Matt! I hope to contribute in the future when I understand all this more. Cheers.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please mark it as an answer with a checkmark.